# Evaluating $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2 - \frac{1}{4}}$ using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Cauchy's Integral Formula states that for $a \in \mathbb{C}$, $r > 0$, if $f:B_r(a) \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, then for every $w \in B_r(a)$ such that $|w-a| < \rho < r$ we have

$$
\int_{|z-a|=\rho} \frac{f(z)}{z-w} dz = 2 \pi \textbf{i}\: f(w).
$$

Here $\gamma$ is the unit circle travelled anti-clockwise, so I have taken $a = 0$ and $\rho = 1$. I see that $\frac{1}{z^2 - \frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right)}$. So I have taken $f(z) = \left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}$, which means $w = \frac{1}{2}$.

The problem now is that $f$ is undefined at $-\frac{1}{2}$, but my open ball must include $\frac{1}{2}$ because $\rho = 1 < r$, hence $f$ is not holomorphic. A similar issue occurs when we take $f(z) = \left(z - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are mistaken: which means $w=-\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{2}$. So it fixes the problem

Comment: Please put the question into the main body, not just the title. What is $\gamma$?

Comment: @Gary, sorry, I forgot to add the actual question into the body. $\gamma$ is the unit circle, so |z|=1.

Comment: @EgorIvanov Why would $w = -\frac{1}{2}$? The formula says otherwise. Besides, the problem here isn't with $w$, its with the point where $f$ isn't defined - if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Ryderr Oh, got it, my bad, sorry. Then perhaps you can try to use residue theorem?

Comment: @EgorIvanov No worries. We haven't learnt the residue theorem yet, and this question was said to be doable with CIF on our problem sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is easily resolved by noting that $\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(z + \frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac 1 {z-\frac 1  2}-\frac 1 {z+\frac 1  2}$ and applying CIF for each of the two terms.